# how to set the controls right aligned with the view in MFC SDI application

Tags: mfc, sdi

I have created a MFC SDI application, and the view is derived from CFormView, so i can put some controls on the dialog. I have put a groupbox at the right side of the dialog and put some other controls inside the groupbox, such as edit box etc.

What i want is the groupbox and the controls inside right aligned with the dialog when i am resizing the view, just like the followingbehavior in C#: set the anchor property of groupbox to be "Right"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [EasySize](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/easysize.aspx) is what i want